# Acrobat "checkedOut" flag. What is it, where can I find it

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, customization, checkout, acrobat

When working with a PDF that is stored on sharepoint with the new AcrobatX, it knows for each file which is checked into sharepoint and which aren't.  For example, if you have 2 documents from sharepoint open for edit, and check one back in before closing, you are prompted about checking in the second one.

Unfortunately, if you check in using a webservice so that you can silently check in on each save, acrobat doesn't know you have checked in a document.  Since it tracks every document you have open, it must have a flag somewhere that you can set, but I have no clue what it is called to be able to set it manually.

Does anyone know what flag needs to be set so that acrobat knows the file is checked in?  If you try and close a document that is already checked in, there are errors that pop up from acrobat wanting to check in too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried contacting Adobe on this, and searched many forums.  I have also tried just attempting to call random things similar to what I want based on what I see of the naming scheme.

With no luck, I have decided this problem cannot be solved without Adobe making a change to Acrobat.  Because of this, as of Acrobat 10.0, I am going to say this cannot be done, and close this question.